# What is this succulent and is it savable?

Tags: identification, succulents

I found this succulent abandoned and I wanted to know what it is and if it is savable. It has some small bump on the brown base part which look like roots.
[image]

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure what it is - perhaps some sort of aloe or agave, but I would stick it in a pot ASAP and give it a bit of water (but use well-drained soil, add a bit of grit if you can). It might survive or it might not... but it certainly won't if you don't give it a chance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's an Haworthia, and may be salvageable. First, you must make sure that the bottom of the plant is completely dry and not mushy or the plant will rot. The easiest way to save it after that is to find a very small pot (or even one cell of a six-pack or four-pack that annuals come in), fill the pot with a 50% sand/50% potting soil mix, and stick the bottom end into the pot. Water ONCE, then wait four weeks and check for roots. Sounds harsh, I know, but I have had about a 50% success rate with this method. Another option you could try, if you have a rock garden, is to wait until the bottom is dry and not mushy, then just stick the bottom of the plant into your rock garden and, again, wait. Note that these are NOT perennial in most places, so if it roots outside be sure to pot it up in the fall and bring inside.